# WordPress and PHP: Removing Parent Slug from Child Page Permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I feel like I'm very close with the code I have so far, but something is still not working. None of the other similar questions on Stack Overflow solve this issue.

I have parent pages and child pages (not posts, not custom post type) in WordPress, and the default mydomain.com/%postname% structure selected.

Currently the permalink structure for pages is mydomain.com/parent-page/child-page

In the backend on the single page editor, the desired permalink displays correctly (with the parent page removed). i.e. mydomain.com/child-page

However when I visit mydomain.com/child-page I get a 404.

I have flushed rewrite rules by visiting the permalink settings page already.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 function wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies( $page_link, $post ) {
    $post = get_post($post);

    $uri = '';

    if($post->post_parent !== 0) {
        $uri = get_post( $post->post_parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
        return str_replace( $uri, '', $page_link );
    } else {
        return $page_link;
    }
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );

function wp_pages_permalink( $permalink_structure, $post_id ) {
    if ( empty( $post_id ) ) return $permalink_structure ;

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if($post->post_parent !== 0) {
        $par = get_post($post->post_parent);
        $parname = $par->post_name . '/';
        $permalink_structure = str_replace( '%pagename%', $post->post_name, $permalink_structure);
        return $permalink_structure;
    }
}

add_filter( 'page_link', 'wp_pages_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I can only get it to work with menu and canonical. The links remove the slug but still on child pages the url redirects. Can't figure that out. Giving up. https://gist.github.com/carasmo/3e6271ccd7b81c3769c68bb07c998e2b

Comment: Hmm I hate to be the guy to recommend a plugin, but I've ran into this issue myself with no solution. This plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ will let you set custom permalinks to however you want. You could look at the repo and try to dissect the code/implement something yourself if you want, or use this.